# How to take input at terminal in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

1. How can I take input at terminal

- Here the first line contain an integer (the size of my array).
- The second line contains integers that describe array 's elements.

I used

```
window.prompt()
```

but it take input only in browser. How can I take input in terminal

```js
function arrayAction(A, N) {
    var temp = []
    var r = window.prompt(N)
    for (var i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        temp.push(window.prompt(A))
        temp.reverse();
    }
    console.log(temp)
}
arrayAction()
```

Comment: How are you expecting the browser and terminal to communicate?

Comment: I want to change the code... Like window.prompt() only can take input on browser... So is there any way to take input in vs code terminal while I run code on VS

Answer (score -1):

if you want to take input you should use this small html and javascript code

```js
var a = document.getElementById("hello").value;
alert(a);
```

```html
<input id="hello" type="text">
<span="hi"your number is</span>
<p></p>
```

```js
var num=document.getElementById("hello")
var te=document.getElementById("out")
function demo(){
  te.innerHTML=num.value;
  //document.write(num.value);

}
```

```html
   <input id="hello" type="number" >
<button onclick="demo()">Click me to get your input number</button>
<br>
<span id="hi">your number is</span>
<p id="out"></p>
```